# How do I send my custom token to another account?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

so this is the custom token i made

```
    address public deployer; //to save adress of the deployer
    
    constructor() ERC20('tokenA', 'TA') { //called by the deployer (once)
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000000 * 10 ** 10); //mint/create tokens - we have created 100000000000*10^18 tokens
        deployer = msg.sender;  //set the deployer
    }

    //total supply is fixed no more can be created ever

    function burn (uint amount) external {  //remove tokens by sending then to a zero address
        _burn(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```

User1 is the owner of the contract and has tons of tokens, User2 has 3 tokens in his wallet.
I have to write a function which when clicked transfers 1 token to the owner that is User1.

```
    function transferOneToken () public payable {
        address token = //address of token contract;
        ERC20 paymentToken = ERC20(token);

        require(paymentToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, owner, 1), "transfer Failed"); //owner is set in constructor
        
    }
```

This is what I came up with, User 2 has 3 tokens and only has to transfer 1 but still gas  estimation failed error pops up saying insufficient allowance

how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token holder (User 2) needs to `approve()` the spender (the contract implementing the `transferOneToken()` function) to spend their tokens before the `transferFrom()` function is invoked.

The `approve()` function of the token contract takes 2 arguments:

1. The spender address
2. The max amount they're allowed to spend

Without the approval mechanism, any contract could pull their users' tokens, which would be an unsafe situation for users who can't/don't read the contract code.

Comment: I added paymentToken.approve(address(this), 1); (in a separate function which user calls prior to this function) but it still shows insufficient balance

Comment: so here is the thing one, I am super grateful for your explanation about 10 people tried none could get this concept through to me secondly, if my user goes to the tokenA contract and manually approves the contract instance it works, but if i call the approve method within the contract instance it does not work. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @HSaad The `approve()` function on the token contract needs to be executed directly from the user address - not through another contract... It's because the `approve()` function checks the `msg.sender` and then stores this approval **from the msg.sender** to the address passed in the param - and when it's invoked through a contract, then the `msg.sender` is the contract address. But you need it to be the user address.

Comment: I understand that but is there a way I can do it through the contract?

Comment: @HSaad No. See my last paragraph in the answer. If it were possible through a contract, there would be many malicious contracts stealing approvals of people who don't read code.

Comment: maybe make a new function which calls the _approve method and pass the msg.sender as a parameter? making sure the msg.sender is the user?

Comment: ah well, I'll just make the user do it manually XD